# Отгрузка товаров 1C-Bitrix

Tags: битрикс

В базе 1C есть такие параметры как вес,высота, ширина, длина, качество товара, новинка до, распродажа до, Цвет. Эти параметры были добавлены. При отгрузки товаров  эти параметра не создались (их нет). Знания небольшие PHP и небольшие знания bitrix. Так понимаю нужно редактировать файлы отгрузки, единственное где они расположены. Есть ли документация по поводу таких вещей ?

Что подскажите ?

Пробовал делать отгрузку в новый каталог но безуспешно!

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в 1С http://prntscr.com/odzfj1 что у тут отмечено. Так же необходимо цену проверить выгружается ли она 

http://prntscr.com/odzgec

http://prntscr.com/odzgjq

Из-за цены могут не выгружаться свойства

 по инструкции выше можено посмотреть внешникод цены

 необходимо проверить что бы он сопавдал с вот этим http://prntscr.com/odziki

 типы цен находится тут http://prntscr.com/odzi2v http://prntscr.com/odzidu 

так-же посмотрите что у вас тут http://prntscr.com/odzheu

Comment: У меня вообще такого нет! https://prntscr.com/oe0gt1

Comment: Редакция 1С какая ? Такого http://prntscr.com/oe0q75 тоже нет нигде?
Да и в любом случае нужно настроить "Тип соглашения об условии продаж" чтобы 1С работало с сайтом

Comment: У меня есть вот это -> https://prnt.sc/oe1pxo . Редакция 2.2.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/oe3xuy редакция 2.2 чего ?

Comment: Управление торговлей для Казахстана, редакция 2.2, модуль обменя с сайтом (2.9.23.3 для УТ 2.2.14)

Comment: К сожалению работал только с новыми версиями обмена. Хотел уточнить что раздел "Тип соглашения об условии продаж" в самой 1С. Попробуйте найти где он находится и настроить

Comment: Так же посмотрел на сайте битрикса (по обмену с сайтом) и не нашел модуля для обмена для вашей редакции https://1c.1c-bitrix.ru/ecommerce/download.php?login=yes

Comment: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=131&CHAPTER_ID=04923&LESSON_PATH=10211.4923 попробуйте почитать тут. Интерфейс вроде похож

Comment: по идее, они должны сами создаться, верно ?  Без вмешательств в отгрузочные файлы?

Comment: По идее да. После того как вы сделаете минимальные настройки со стороны 1С, все должно начать передаваться. Но это по версии битрикса. В случае интеграции с 1С столько нюансов. У вас ещё и не последняя версия обмена. Иногда проще сделать ручную интеграцию, да затратно, но ты всегда знаешь что и как происходит

Comment: Верно, я согласен с вами. Есть ли документация, или статьи которые описывают как это работает. Чтобы мог почитать.